# Why is magento So Slow On Windows

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I have recently started working on Magento. I work in my office on Ubuntu (Linux) operating System. The speed of magento is quite good at my office. It takes very little time to load the pages. However I have installed the same version of Magento on my Laptop. I cannot understand why is there so much variation in loading pages. It sometimes takes 2 - 3 minutes to load the admin page or a product Category page. Other applications run quite well on my system. Please help..

Comment: One possibility is that you have APC cache installed at the office and don't have it on home PC

Comment: one reason can be that Magento on windows is not officially supported?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, start using a VirtualMachine with a Linux flavor instead of a WAMP stack.

Comment: Depends on your laptop. It's probably way below spec and since it's a workstation, it's running a lot of fiddle-futz that steals away from the processing power Magento needs to run. If you're going to run Magento on workstation class computers, an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS virtual machine on a Windows 7 64bit quad-core i7-960 with 8GB can run with enough speed to deliver 2 second HTML loads. Give the VM 2GB memory, the php interpreter memory_limit set to 512MB for those larger Magento installations and tune MySQL to perform faster than it will on your "shared hosting simulator WAMP installation".

Comment: In fact my laptop and my Office machine both have almost Same configuration, my laptop has slightly greater wth respect to RAM.. I don't know If its a Problem with Wamp, Magento or Operating System

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up a side-by-side comparison of the hardware and disk subsystems on a spreadsheet to see if there are any hidden major differences (almost the same config). Magento's PHP/Zend framework application needs a fast processor and plenty of memory. Its MySQL database depends on memory for buffering, but needs a fast disk I/O environment. So, the first step is to figure out what's the choke point under Windows. I'd start with MySQL memory pools and parameter tuning and then go from there. Apache PHP DSO is a notorious resource sink, probably moreso on Windows.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I think Its Because Of Operating System. Try Doing Disk De-fragmentation in Xp and use Some registery Cleaner to speed up ur Xp.

Comment: This comment doesn't address the issue at all

Answer (score 1):

I think the most obvious reason is the hardware spec of the server vs your laptop (ie disk speed / memory), but this answer gives a lot of pointers -> [Why is Magento so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639213/why-is-magento-so-slow)

Comment: In fact my laptop and my Office machine both have almost Same configuration, my laptop has slightly greater wth respect to RAM.. I don't know If its a Problem with Wamp, Magento or Operating System