# Optimising Magento loading speed - how to identify why initial receiving so slow

Tags: performance, magento, optimization

While our website is not yet complete graphically and design wise, most of the backend operations are near completion.

However, after optimising the MySQL database we are still receiving a significant initial receiving period when tested on pingdom.com:

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/IuoBna86v/http://foscam-uk.com

According to Pingdom:

The yellow part is the time it takes to resolve the hostname and similar (before the connection is initiated to the web server), the green part is connecting to the web server, and the blue part is the time it takes to retrieve the content from the webserver.

Upon asking our managed VPS support team we got the response:

> Have you tried optimizing your script? I believe that the high wait time on there indicates actual website loading time (meaning for your script to load); not actual connection to the website/server.

Now, Pingdom shows the JS/CSS loading relatively quickly, the MySQL database side of things doesn't seem to be slowing anything down either - I am seeking suggestions of what this could be or what might be causing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639213/why-is-magento-so-slow

Answer (score 0):

1. 89 requests are too many.
2. Reduce number of image request by creating sprites.This is pretty important from what is shown in pingdom.
3. Keep Alive should be set to On and Keep alive time should be a bit higher(15 seconds or so).
4. Use of compiler plus merge and minify js/css is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Change the hosting provider. 8 second loading is very very slow. It means that it actually is around 15-17 seconds for a user that doesn't have cached parts of your site (first time visitor). My site www.bebepunk.ro loads according to pingdom in 2.5 seconds and users still complain about the slowness of the site. Check also with http://www.webpagetest.org for both values.