# Why is magento so slow? Wait up to 35 seconds

Tags: php, magento

Magento gives a very late response. Wait up to 35 seconds.

The server where it is hosted serves other non-Magento sites super fast. What is it about the PHP code that Magento uses that makes it so slow, and what can be done to fix it?
also, I use MaxCDN for media files

Comment: _server where it is hosted serves other non-Magento sites super fast_ usually isn't a good indicator of much. Your web hosting service needs to understand optimizing servers to run Magento and if this is on a shared hosting service, must be willing to give Magento the resources it needs. Magento does not play well with others. This is basically a Magento server requirements question  being asked in a programming section.

Comment: I agree totally with the above comment. Good general-use web hosting does not guarantee your magento eshop will run fast. Anyway, if changing your provider is not an option, you could have a look at plugins which increase magento's speed like http://www.aitoc.com/en/magento_booster.html

Answer (score 0):

This is really a non constructive question. However here are some resources that could lead to your particular answer:

[Magento Server Requirements](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements)

[Top 7 Reasons Your Magento Site Is Slow](http://anattadesign.com/blog/slow-magento-sites/)

[Previous SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639213/why-is-magento-so-slow)