# Magento admin panel and site are really slow and aren't working on localhost

Tags: php, magento, xampp, e-commerce, magento2

I just installed Magento CE on XAMPP with the intent to start developing with it. Both the admin panel and the site itself are loading extremely slow. The site takes about 30 seconds to load and does so without any images. The admin panel takes about 20 seconds and loads with no images as well. **It's also not working at all. When I try to go to a category such as Products nothing happens.**

Comment: enable all cache and generate all static content , first it will take time after that will work perfect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Magento so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639213/why-is-magento-so-slow)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your static deploy is not complete.
first remove your pub/static files then run below command in command prompt:
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

after that refresh your page(better delete browser cache too) and let it load completely. Then only your admin will work properly.
For overall performance,
Try increasing your memory_limit parameter in my.ini to 1024 OR 2048 and restart apache.