# How to fix" Website loading issues" Magenot2?

Tags: magento2

Consider lazy-loading offscreen and hidden images after all critical resources have finished loading to lower time to interactive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Magento so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639213/why-is-magento-so-slow)

Comment: Can you clarify your question please ? You want to speed-up your Magento ?